# Restful api custom types

Tags: api, rest

So I am building a restful api allowing users to send events.

There are "standard" events like birthday, wedding, etc that each have their separate properties. So if someone sends data for type = birthday they can also specify the parameters date_of_birthday, new_age, etc. If they send type = wedding, for example, they have to specify different properties.

So basically when they make /event/create api call, they specify a type and a list of properties based on that type. If they want to specify a "custom" type they can. In that case the properties they specify are up to them.

How best to build this api so that it is true to rest?

Answer (score 0):

To create an event, clients should make a POST request like

HTTP POST: /event

The post parameters should contain the event details and can be of any structure that the application understands.

Answer (score 0):

Create events using POST, this request it self stands for "Create new" event. I would also suggest following structure of your API URIs:

```
POST /event/birthday             //Create new birthday event
POST /event/wedding              //Create new wedding event
...
```

generally:

```
POST /event/{event_name}
```

this will help you provide clear structure of the RESTful API. E.g. getting all event types can be retrieved with `GET /event`, getting all birthdays with `GET /event/birthday`, getting weddings on 1.1.2014 `GET /event/wedding/1-1-2014` etc

Think of your resource URI structure in the same way, you will define a folders and files structure.

Comment: How would you implement the custom type?

Comment: It depends on programming language and "framework" you are using to implement RESTful API. Check documentation for particular details.